# How to exclude results having (or not) a specific value in a collection?

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

let's say I have an entity more or less like this (pseudo code):

```
class Contact {
   String name;
   String surname;
   List<Address> addresses;
}

class Address {
   String streetName;
   String type;
}
* let's say every field is correctly annotated with @Field / @Indexed / @Embeddable etc
```

Using jpa hibernate-search I can get every contact correctly using full-text-queries and fuzzy, but I cannot find a way to limit the search only to 
`name or surname or (addresses.streetName but only if addresses.type="XYZ")`. I don't want it to search into streetNames when they're not of the type xyz.

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query baseQuery = qb
                .keyword()
                .fuzzy()
                .onFields("name", "surname")
                .matching(String.join("+", queryStrings))
                .createQuery();


org.apache.lucene.search.Query addressQueryRestriction = qb.keyword()
                .onField("addresses.type")
                .matching("XYZ")
                .createQuery();

org.apache.lucene.search.Query addressQuery = qb.fuzzy()
                .onFields("addresses.streetName")
                .matching(String.join("+", queryStrings))
                .createQuery();

org.apache.lucene.search.Query queryAddressComposite = qb
                .bool()
                    .must(addressQuery)
                    .must(addressQueryRestriction)
                .createQuery();

org.apache.lucene.search.Query finalQuery = qb
                .bool()
                    .should(baseQuery)
                    .should(queryAddressComposite)
                .createQuery();
```

I've been trying a lot by composing alternative queries with .bool().must() / should() / must().not() but without too much success. Especially when a contact has an XYZ address but also others that aren't.
I'm starting to thing it's a logical issue here, as I'm looking into a list, but if you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong please blast me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you indexed-embed a list of addresses in your document, and want to apply conditions to each of these addresses, rather than to all of them merged together, you need to index each object as a nested document and then use a "nested" predicate.

The concept of nested documents exists in Hibernate Search 6 (still in Beta), but not in Hibernate Search 5.

I would recommend that you upgrade.

See [this section of the Hibernate Search 6 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexedembedded-storage) for more information.